# jQueryUI DatePicker - Add click events to dates outside of minDate and maxDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using 2 jQueryUI DatePickers to select a start and end date. My requirements are that I must specify a start and end date separately, rather than selecting a date range on a single calendar.

When I select the start date, I set the `minDate` of the end date to be equal to it. Vice versa with the end date.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
   dateFormat: 'DD dd-mm-yy',
   onSelect: function () {
      SetMinMaxValuesOfDatePickers();
   }
});

static SetMinMaxValuesOfDatePickers() {
   let newMinDate = $('#start-date').datepicker('getDate');
   let newMaxDate = $('#end-date').datepicker('getDate');

   if (newMinDate != null) {
      $('#end-date').datepicker('change', { minDate: newMinDate });
   }
   if (newMaxDate != null) {
      $('#start-date').datepicker('change', { maxDate: newMaxDate });
   }
}
```

The disabling of the dates before the `minDate` and `maxDate` gives me a partial range selector that suits my needs better than an actual range selector.

[image]

However, I want the user to be able to click dates **before** the `minDate` and for it to reset the `min`/`maxDate` on both DatePickers. I tried to achieve this by adding a click event to the disabled cells in the calendar:

```
$('.ui-state-disabled').on('click', function () {
   alert("This doesn't appear!");
   $("#start-date").datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
   $("#end-date").datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
});
```

Unfortunately, these click events never trigger. I couldn't even select the disabled `<td>`s in *inspect element*. I investigated and found the CSS property `pointer-events: none;` was being applied to each of the disabled `<td>`s. Removing that allowed me to select disabled cells in the debugger, but I could never get the click events to fire.

Can someone assist me with this? If I can get the events to fire when a user clicks a disabled date I can do it.

Comment: Juest so we're clear, you want to set the min/max dates but allow the user to select dates outside of the min/max range?  This is exactly *not* setting min/max dates.  I think you need to rethink your implementation... Can you be a little more clear re: your specifications?  "However, I want the user to be able to click dates before the minDate and for it to reset the min/maxDate on both DatePickers" is confusing

Comment: @LeroyStav Yes, this was a hacky solution using the min/max date as a start and end date in what is effectively a range picker. I went for this because existing range pickers for jQuery UI's DatePicker didn't do the job particularly well. I was clutching at straws with this solution and in the end I forwent the rangepicker aspect and just had plain start/end dates; easier and less hacky, but not as nice for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided against using the min/max date as a form of range picker. It was too hacky and messy. I ended up forgoing the range picker aspect of this little widget and just went with plain start date and end date.

@user1477388 - that code is very similar to what I tried and it still did not detect a click event.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of adding a trigger on the disabled item should work.  My guess is you're defining it before the datepicker.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-disabled').click(function() {
    alert('invalid date selected');
});
```

Please see this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/6694/